# Audio capture tool

Tags: software-rec, audio, recording, capture

I'm looking for a free audio tool for capturing the audio that's playing on my computer to a wav/mp3, etc.

I've been messing around with
http://lab.andre-michelle.com/tonematrix

and would like to capture the results of my labor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try Audacity, multiplatform, nice and powerful, does MP3 export via plugin.

http://audacity.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Audacity is a fantastic program.